# What is וְשָׁם referring to in יוֹם שַׁבָּתוֹן?

Tags: shabbat, shabbat-songs, yom-shabbaton

> וְשָׁם יָנוּחוּ יְגִיעֵי כֹחַ

What does the word שָׁם refer to in יוֹם שַׁבָּתוֹן and where will the  יְגִיעֵי כֹחַ rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the Ya'avetz: Noah sent the Yonah (dove?) the seventh day which was Shabath and it finally found a place to rest. In addition Knesset Yisrael which is meshula (analogic to? symbolized by?) the yonah will find rest in Shabatah. In addition the Gehenom so-called is "closed" in Shabath so the reshayim have a day of rest. My addition:  Sham which generally means a place is here used in the sense of a "place in time" .

Answer (score 2):

This fragment is actually a quotation from Sefer Iyov ([3:17](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%96)):

> שָׁם רְשָׁעִים חָדְלוּ רֹגֶז וְשָׁם יָנוּחוּ יְגִיעֵי כֹחַ:‏

In the original pasuk, the reference is to death (or the grave; but same idea).

In the song, "Sham" refers to Shabbat itself.

I would suggest that the context of the quotation lends itself to (as in Rony's answer) the wicked resting from Gehinnom on Shabbat, and a hint of the final stage of creation, [the eternal shabbat](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%96_%D7%93):

> לעתיד לבוא ליום שכלו שבת מנוחה לחיי העולמים:‏